# How to replace bootstrap-select with select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, bootstrap-select

I have used `bootstrap-select` through out the application. Now am supposed  to replace `bootstrap-select` with `select2` with the same styling. What would be the fastest and efficient way to change the `js` part?

For example:

In bootstrap-select there are methods and options, like `selectpicker('refresh'),selectpicker('show'),selectpicker('c‌​lose')`etc whereas in `select2`, methods are `open,close` etc. Eventhough i replace those `bootstrap-select` methods with less similar `select2` methods, I don't get the same result and getting weird behaviour. Many methods are not available in `select2` as in `bootstrap-select`

Now how can I update those codes with `select2` in a efficienty way?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap3?

Answer (score 2):

I think You can use only those Bootstrap CSS which have used to applied to your select2 dropdown.

You need to identify which part of CSS is used from bootstrap to display your select2 drop down properly. And then you can remove Bootstrap CSS and use that CSS only to apply the style for your select2 dropdown.

Another option is You will find that CSS part from [this](http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/) link. If you are using Bootstrap3.

Thanks.

Comment: Not only css what about the js part?